# HOW to prove this?

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory

Suppose that f(n) ∈ O(log2(n)). Can we say that 2^f(n) ∈ O(n)?
I may be confusing myself but mathematically wouldn't this be true? Since 2^log2(n) would be n, and n would be an element of O(n) in terms of complexity? However, how would I prove this?

Comment: I think this question should be posted at cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Neither one is true.  2^n is not linear in n; log(n) is not n.  You need to understand Big-Oh notation.

Comment: @duffymo If someone asks for help with Big-Oh notation, then commenting that they need to understand Big-Oh notation is a bit redundant. (And more than a little bit condescending, if you ask me.)

Comment: This is a case of "check your assumptions".  The OP made some statements that seem incorrect.  Maybe the reason for the question is bad assumptions.  If those were to change, the question would go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not true. You can transform to

```
2^f(n) = n^O(1)
```

as `f(n) < c*log2(n)` (for large `n`) only implies

```
2^f(n) < 2^(c*log2(n)) = (2^log2(n))^c = n^c
```

with some undisclosed constant `c`.